# What does 'put up with' mean in context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'put up with' mean in comtext?

> —Home, Meg thought comfortably, and regarded her parents and brothers
>   with affectionate gratitude. They had **put up with** her all through her
>   **prickly** adolescence, and she still did not feel very grown up.

A Swiftly Tilting Planet
by MADELEINE L’ENGLE

Comment: This doesn't seem difficult to find. Searching Google returned many relevant results, including [put up with](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/put-up-with-sth-sb) (Cambridge Dictionary). If the dictionary did not answer your question, please [edit] your post to explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Collins,

> If you **put up with** something, you tolerate or accept it, even though you find it unpleasant or unsatisfactory.

During the entire period of her growing up from being a child into an adult,  her parents and brothers had to tolerate/endure/bear her rude and inappropriate behavior or tolerate her meltdowns, lack of communication, carelessness, etc.

> Collins says "something that is prickly feels rough and uncomfortable, as if it has a lot of prickles. Someone who is prickly loses their temper or gets upset very easily" (like teenagers). Cambridge defines prickly as "complicated and difficult to deal with."

Answer (score 0):

It means that her family "tolerated" and "endured" her behavior during that time.